# Copy value of 1 variable into another variable in UNIX

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

New to Unix not aware of the syntax structure so please excuse my syntax brevity.I am trying to copy a value of a variable and store that in another variable eg:

Two variables:

1. `abc`
2. `bcd`

Given:

```
abc=123
```

I want to copy the contents of `abc` i.e 123 in `bcd`. How to achieve this in Unix?

Earlier I was trying to copy the contents of `abc` in a `.txt` file which was working for me: see the code snippet below:

```
abc='123'
echo $abc >>/data/test/tt.txt
```

But know I want to copy them in another variable so I tried to do the following but was of no success.

```
    abc='123'
    test=`echo $abc>>bcd`
    echo $test
```

Can you assist me in this?

Comment: Did you try `bcd=$abc` ?

Comment: Hey @vidit that works, i have a scenario where the value of abc will be incremented eg: abc="123" then abc="456" i want bcd to have both the values

Comment: you expect a variable to have two values? Maybe you should look into Quantum Mechanics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy:

```
bcd="$abc"
```

For example:

```
abc="hello world"
```

The quotes there are necessary or else it will try to run a command named `world` with `abc` in its environment.

Actually, the quotes are not necessary (thanks to 1_CR for pointing this), but I like to add them for readability:

```
bcd=$abc
bcd="$abc"
```

They both do the same, exactly what you need.

Lastly, do not use single quotes, or else you will not get the value of the variable:

```
bcd='$abc'
```

Error! Now your `bcd` variable contains the literal value `$abc`.

Comment: [Quotes not needed](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/97569/21233) in ksh variable assignment apparently

Comment: Yes the above works, but what in a scenario where the value of abc will be incremented eg abc="123" then abc="456" now here i want bcd to have both the values which are bcd="123 456" how can we achieve this?

Comment: @1_CR: You are right! They are not needed in bash either! You always learn something in SO, even in the apparently easiest questions.

Comment: To _increment_ the variable you'll do `abc="$abc 456"`. And here the quotes are necessary. Or if you don't want the space: `abc=${abc}456`, then you don't need the quotes.

Comment: I can do that when i know the what the next incremented value of abc will be like in this case abc="$abc 456" what if we do not knw what the next value will be

Comment: @Rahulsawant: Sorry, I don't understand this new question. I think it will be better if you open a new question and clarify what you are trying to do (examples, code and such).

Comment: @Rahulsawant: To add the new string to the end of $abc, just do `bcd="$bcd $abc"`

Comment: Quotes avoid some bad shell interpretation. Ex: var="echo ${PATH}" is taking the value of path, var='echo ${PATH}' is taking the string litteraly (without translation of PATH value) and var=echo ${PATH} will create an error.